# Log an event in browsers' console log when contact is online/offline on whatsapp

Tags: javascript, browser, notifications, whatsapp

I have come across [this](https://www.greasyfork.org/en/scripts/17410-whatsapp-online-notifier/code) script that logs an event in console when the contact in focus on whatsapp web comes online.

```
waitForElementId("main", function(node) {

  console.log("Main panel loaded.")

  var handleTextNode = function(textNode) {
      if(textNode.textContent == 'online')
      {
        console.log("User is online");
        notifyUser();
      }
  };
```

Can someone please help extend the function and display another event in log when contact goes offline?
Thank you.

Comment: This cannot be the complete script. Where is `handleTextNode` used?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have [linked](https://www.greasyfork.org/en/scripts/17410-whatsapp-online-notifier/code) the full code in the post.

Comment: Hey, does this code still work nowadays? I would try myself but my understanding of the code is limited and not sure if it does not work because of me or because of the code.